# App not showing up in TestFlight App

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

My app has been uploaded successfully to iTunes connect, and I've selected the most recent version for testing:

[image]

However, it does not show up in the TestFlight app. And i'm signed into the iCloud account that is an internal tester for this app. Not sure why it's not showing up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I needed to go through the invite email first. My bad, but hopefully this clears it up for someone assuming it will automatically show up in the TestFlight app.